# django-filter get queryset

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am using [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/guide/usage.html) v1.1.0 , django 1.11. I want a dynamic filter for a model. I have created filters.py which contains the respective config for model filters. [This site](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/28/how-to-filter-querysets-dynamically.html) tells that:

> It will generate a Django Form with the search fields as well as
>   return the filtered QuerySet.

It here refers to `SomeModelFilter` function. I tried applying `len` and `objects` functions to it's object, but it returns

```
AttributeError: 'SomeModelFilter' object has no attribute 'len'
AttributeError: 'SomeModelFilter' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

I want to get the filtered content. It doesn't seem to be a QuerySet to me.

**filters.py**

```
from project_app.models import *
import django_filters


class SomeModelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ['field_a', 'field_b', 'field_c', 'field_d']
```

**views.py**

```
    somemodel_list = SomeModel.objects.all()
    somemodel_filter = SomeModelFilter(request.GET, queryset=somemodel_list)

    print(len(somemodel_filter)) # This gives the first error
    print(somemodel_filter.objects.all()) # This gives the second error
```

I want to get the filtered content, hopefully which is contained in `somemodel_filter` object.

Comment: Can you post full view code?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner, other part of the code is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Looks like error raised somewhere after `somemodel_filter` initialization. It would be great if you could add view and full traceback also.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner have added print statements which give error. I think this should be enough. I just want the content of `somemodel_filter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this line `print(somemodel_filter.objects.all())`. `somemodel_filter` is not model, it's filterset instance and since it's don't have `objects` attribute. To get filtered queryset use `qs` attribute, like this:

```
print(somemodel_filter.qs)
```

You can find example of filter usage [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/guide/usage.html#the-template).

Comment: How to handle filter based on foreign key field ?

Comment: @OmkarDeshpande same as any other field, by default you should pass id to filter by foreignkey.

Answer (score 0):

```
filtered_data = ExampleFilter(requet.Get, queryset=Example.objects.all())
```

## to get the filtered queryset

```
filtered_queryset_data = filtered_data.qs
```

## Use serializer to serialize the data. Use many=true since the its a list

```
serialized_data = ExampleSerializer(filtered_queryset_data, many=true).data
```